# Plotly Dash and callbacks that invoke multiprocessing code

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, plotly-dash

I recently started putting together a webapp with Plotly Dash. I have a callback function that updates a DataTable with data that are fetched from a Redis server. The code that connects to Redis and downloads the data was originally developed to be used elsewhere - in scripts that run standalone either from the command line or through scheduling systems. The scripts run fine. The code that fetches the data can be run either sequentially or in parallel via multiprocessing. The multiprocessing related code is typical for the use case, it creates two queues, one with tasks pending and one for the completed tasks. An infinite while loop listens on the completed tasks queue and picks up the completed tasks until all of the tasks are finished. The reason why multiprocessing is used is because for each key/value pair fetched from Redis, the value is a big object that needs unpickling which is relatively time consuming.

To cut the long story short, when the code gets executed via the Dash callback function, the tasks are inserted in the pending queue, the infinite while loop listens on the tasks completed queue but no tasks are getting executed. For some reason in the example below the function `do_work` never gets executed by any worker at all

```
    # Set-up and start the workers
    for c in range(num_workers):
        p = mp.Process(target=do_work, args=(tasks_pending, tasks_completed, verbose))
        p.name = 'worker' + str(c)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
```

I did have a look around multiprocessing context managers and Flask etc but I didn't manage to make it work. Any idea what is going on and why Dash (or Flask) is a special case? Any hints or pointers to the right direction would be great.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use define a multiprocessing Queue and then pass it to the callback via app.

```
events_messages = multiprocessing.Queue()

app.queue = events_messages
```

then you can add messages or read them in the callback function:

```
app.queue.put('your item for the Queue')
```